# JAVASCRIPT REDUCER NOT ACCUMULATING WITH CONTEXT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

building a demo budget and my code is functioning but the expenses array is not accumulating in the below function.

```
        {value => {
            const totalExpense = value.expenses.length > 0 ? (
                value.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    acc += curr.amount
                    return acc
                }, 0)) : 0;
            console.log(totalExpense);
            console.log(value.expenses);
```

Comment: So what is the issue? hard to tell from this snipplet of code.

Answer (score 1):

Works on my machine.

Hard to say without knowing what the data looks like, so I took a stab below:

```js
const value = {
  expenses: [{amount: 1}, {amount: 2}]
}

const totalExpense = value.expenses.length > 0 ? (
  value.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc += curr.amount
    return acc
  }, 0)) : 0;
  
console.log(totalExpense);
console.log(value.expenses);
```

You can also simplify it further with the following changes:

```js
const value = {
  expenses: [{amount: 1}, {amount: 2}]
}

// no need to check length
const totalExpense = value.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount, 0);
  
console.log(totalExpense);
console.log(value.expenses);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        {value => {
            const totalExpense = value.expenses.length > 0 ? (
                value.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    acc += parseInt(curr.amount)
                    return acc
                }, 0)) : 0;
            console.log(totalExpense);
            console.log(value.expenses);
```

curr.amount wasnt coming accross as an integer so it needed to be parseInt'd